# How to get key from json array specified in the function parameter without looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have sample json array:

```
var jsonArray = '{"name":"Otabek","lastName":"Mansurov","age":"16"}';
```

And I have sample function:

```
function getError(jsonArray, arrayKeyFromJsonArray) {
    var looping = $.parseJSON(jsonArray);
    $.each(looping, function(key, value) {
        if(key.toLowerCase() == arrayKeyFromJsonArray.toLowerCase()) {
            console.log(key + '=' + value);
        } else console.log("Sorry, I can't found key " + arrayKeyFromJsonArray + " from array!");
    });
}
```

Example using:

```
getError(jsonArray, 'age'); // Return: age = 16
```

Is it possible to find the key from an array without a loop?

Example new function pseudocode:

```
function getError(jsonArray, arrayKeyFromJsonArray) {
    return jsonArray.arrayKeyFromJsonArray;
}
```

Comment: That's not an array, that's an object. Also, `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonArray); return obj[arrayKeyFromJsonArray]`.

Comment: Use Object.keys(data) will give you an array of all key's

Comment: Your data structure is an object, so you can simply access its values: `var jsonObj = JSON.parse( '{"name":"Otabek","lastName":"Mansurov","age":"16"}'); console.log(jsonObj.age)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible by using a lazy style, because keys are case sensitive.

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and check the value and if not `undefined` take it as key for the object.

```js
function getError(json, search) {
    var object = JSON.parse(json),
        key = Object.keys(object).find(k => k.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase());
        
    return key !== undefined
        ? object[key]
        : "Sorry, I can't find key " + search + " in array!"
}

var json = '{"name":"Otabek","lastName":"Mansurov","age":"16"}';

console.log(getError(json, 'age'));
console.log(getError(json, 'lastname'));
console.log(getError(json, 'foo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want  to get key data dynamically because use don't know what will be the key.
For this situation you can try something like

> looping[arrayKeyFromJsonArray]

```
function getError(jsonArray, arrayKeyFromJsonArray) {
    var looping = $.parseJSON(jsonArray);
    console.log(arrayKeyFromJsonArray + '=' + looping[arrayKeyFromJsonArray]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to check for errors too, and you can use `in` keyword :

```js
var jsonArray = '{"name":"Otabek","lastName":"Mansurov","age":"16"}';
function getError(jsonArray, arrayKeyFromJsonArray) {
  var looping = $.parseJSON(jsonArray);
  if( arrayKeyFromJsonArray in looping )
      return looping[arrayKeyFromJsonArray];
   else {
      console.log("key not found");
      return undefined; // or null
   }
}

console.log( getError( jsonArray, "age" ) );
console.log( getError( jsonArray, "XXX" ) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```